# How can I prevent a {switch} tag from cycling unless a Switchee case or advanced conditional is true?

Tags: add-on, conditionals, switch, advanced-conditionals

I have a channel entry loop that is outputting entries from three different channels. Entries from each channel are marked up differently, so I have a Switchee case with the value of `channel_short_name` to determine which channel the entry is in and then output the appropriate markup.

```
{exp:switchee variable="{channel_short_name}" parse="inward"}

{case value="channel_one"}

... (Channel one markup)

{/case}

{case value="channel_two"}

... (Channel two markup)

{/case}

{case value="channel_three"}

... (Channel three markup)

{/case}

{/exp:switchee}
```

Within one channel, I need to have two different layouts (based on status) and cycle between classes. I'm trying to accomplish this by nesting another Switchee case using `status` as the value and `{switch}` to cycle classes.

```
{exp:switchee variable="{channel_short_name}" parse="inward"}

{case value="channel_one"}

... (Channel one markup)

{/case}

{case value="channel_two"}

... (Channel two markup)

{/case}

{case value="channel_three"}

   {switchee variable="{status}" parse="inward"}

   {case value="Featured"}

   <div class="channel-three featured">
      <div class="{switch="class-a|class-b}"></div>
   </div>

   {/case}

   {case default="yes"}

   <div class="channel-three not-featured">
      <div class="{switch="class-one|class-two|class-three}"></div>
   </div>

   {/case}

   {/switchee}
{/case}

{/exp:switchee}
```

Finally, the issue I am having is the `{switch}` markup nested in Switchee seems to cycle on every entry, wether the case it is wrapped in is true or not.

The output is something like this.

```
<div class="channel-three featured">
   <div class="class-a"></div><!-- Expecting class-a -->
</div>

<div class="channel-three not-featured">
   <div class="class-two"></div><!-- Expecting class-one -->
</div>

<div class="channel-three featured">
   <div class="class-a></div><!-- Expecting class-b -->
</div>
```

Is `{switch}` working as expected? Is there a different approach I should take on this? Any other plugins I should try?

Comment: Are you for sure running the dev branch version?

Comment: Is your 2nd case actually "Featured" or "featured" I believe its case sensitive.

Comment: @Natetronn, yes I am running the dev branch version. stuartmcd69, The 2nd case is actually "Featured". I've also tried using {switch} unnested and it also iterates when the case value is not met.

Comment: the switch is incrementing for EACH channel:entries step. i don't think hiding it within an IF or Switchee statement does matter

Answer (score 1):

This can probably be done on the CSS side of things also. Just set the class to something to identify the channel and use `nth-child(3n+0)` to style them differently.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp